# SVG—convert Units to use in SVGMatrix

Tags: svg

I am about to write a routine that expands `<use>` elements such that these elements are replaced by the full DOM tree, as described [here](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/single-page.html#struct-UseElement)

The specs say:

> An additional transformation translate(x,y) is appended to the end (i.e., right-side) of the ‘transform’ attribute on the generated ‘g’, where x and y represent the values of the ‘x’ and ‘y’ attributes on the ‘use’ element

But those values for `x` and `y` may be given like: `10%`, so I have created a tiny helper routine like that:

```
createLength (value) {
  const
    l = root.createSVGLength(),
    parsed = parseFloat(value),
    parsedUnit = value
      .replace(parsed.toString(), '')
      .replace(/^\s*/m, '')
      .replace(/\s*$/m, ''),
    //UNITS is a map like:
    //{px: SVGLength.SVG_LENGTHTYPE_PX, … }
    unit = UNITS.hasOwnProperty(parsedUnit) ?
      UNITS[parsedUnit] : UNITS.number
  ;
  l.newValueSpecifiedUnits(unit, parsed);
  return l;
}
```

which successfully creates instances of `SVGLength`. Later in the code I want to create the bespoken `SVGTransform` which »is appended to the end[…]«, like this:

```
   const [x,y,width,height] = 
      ['x','y','width','height']
        .map(attr => node.getAttribute(attr))
        .map(val => this.createLength(val))
    ;

    expanded.transform.baseVal
      .appendItem(
        root.createSVGTransformFromMatrix(
          this.matrix(1,0,0,1,
            x.value,
            y.value)));
```

What throws this error in chromium, if the given value for `x` or `y` is in percentages:

```
DOMException: Failed to read the 'value' property from 'SVGLength': Could not resolve relative length.
```

`expanded` is a reference which is meant to be the replacement of the `<use>`, which is not attached to a parent node at the time, when the value is assigned.

What is the mistake here?

Comment: Why not use the SVG DOM instead of parseFloat? Anyway your main issue is that SVG transforms don't support percentages, you'd need to converting the percentage to a pixel value.

Comment: »Why not use the SVG DOM instead« — how do you mean that? »you'd need to converting the percentage to a pixel value« — That is exactly what I am after, but it throws the error as stated in my question. I have also tried: `x.convertToSpecifiedUnits(UNITS.number)`, but that created the same error…

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SVGLength

Comment: @RobertLongson Thanks, your comment gave me the clue…

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to the comment of @RobertLongson I could finally make it work. Instead of  creating a new instance of `SVGLength`, based on the attribute's string value (obtained by `node.getAttribute('x')`), I just used `node.x.baseVal.value` for the matrix.

As the docs say for [`<svg>.createSVGLength()`](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/single-page.html#struct-__svg__SVGSVGElement__createSVGLength):

> Creates an SVGLength object **outside of any document trees**.

Since percentages are relative to values from parent nodes, it is not possible to convert those to numbers, since there is no scale present.

`node.x.baseVal` also yields the `SVGLength`, but that one is »inside of any document trees«, so it is possible to convert from pixel to number.